# Adding elements in C# List variable initialized as array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have initialized a list in C# as follows:

```
List<int[]> X1 = new List<int[]>();
```

Now I wanted to know the procedure for inserting elements in 'X1'? The usual Add() does not work. So can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: "The usual Add() does not work". Yes it does. `X1.Add(new [] { 1 });`

Comment: Next time though, you should put what you've tried to do and we can explain what it is you did wrong. You probably tried X1.Add(7) or something which wouldn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: What do you think that code means? Do you want a list of arrays, or do you want a list which *is* an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Add()` should work so long as you're adding an array of `int`'s.

```
List<int[]> X1 = new List<int[]>();
X1.Add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

This is because X1 is a list that holds arrays.

Answer (score 6):

Huh? X1 isn't an array. You add items with `X1.Add(...);` An example would be

```
X1.Add(new int[] { 1 });
```